# How do I disable clipping in a compose view in xml

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to disable clipping so an item in my compose view clips but im not entirely sure how to go about doing this, my compose view is in xml so it looks a bit like this

```
    <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
    android:id="@+id/viewId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    >
```

Inside the compose view i have an image that i want to disable clipping on with the following configuration.

```
       Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = image),
            contentDescription = "home",
            modifier = Modifier
                .offset(xvalue.dp, yValue.dp)
                .background(color = colorResource(R.color.Green), shape = CircleShape)
                .height(25.dp)
                .width(25.dp)
                .padding(5.dp).zIndex(20f).graphicsLayer { clip = false },
            colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(Color.White)
        )
```

From what Ive read up on using clip=false should work but it doesn't.

Comment: By default Compose views doesn't clip content. Most probably it's done by XML container. Have you tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044085/when-drawing-outside-the-view-clip-bounds-with-android-how-do-i-prevent-underli)?

Comment: Yeah, i have clip children set to false and it still clips

Comment: The image is inside a container view or it is just the image?

Comment: it's inside a box composable but i have clip=false on the box